# How to install Ubuntu 16 alongside with Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

I have MSI gp62m Laptop. I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD and mounted one folder on HDD.
So, my partition scheme is :

```
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 118.8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 390.6G  0 part /StorageFolder
```

How could I install Ubuntu 16 on HDD, so I could choose to run it in the grub menu?

Comment: There is no limit for "OS entries" to grub ( I have up to ~40 ). ... Ubuntu 16.04 will automatically include boot entries for 18.04 .

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yup, but when I choose install alongside with Ubuntu 18 - after the installation there are multiple options for Ubuntu 18 only, not Ubuntu 16